# problem with libssl

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am having a problem when installing a library and when executing the command "sudo apt --fix-broken install" it throws me the following error

```
> sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl0.9.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl0.9.8
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/692 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,445 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 278901 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl0.9.8:amd64 (0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you need outdated libssl0.9.8 to be installed? Which application needs it?

Comment: My version of ubuntu is 20.04 and I need it to install the ClamAV antivirus

Comment: ClamAV is packaged https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/clamav . You are inventing new bicycle with rectangular wheels.